# sed with multi line selecting with regex

Tags: regex, sed, replace, find

I need grab a file that was converted (firewall migration) and it adds a huge comments section. I want to replace everything between the ("").

So, in this example, I want to have the output say

```
set comments " "
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
sed 's/.*set comments* ".*"/set comment "" /' %filename% >> %outputfilename%
```

The problem is that some of the "comments" have multi-line and with my command, it does not take that into account.  So the ones without the /r or /n in them work fine.

Actual File

```
set action accept    
set comments "access-list inside_access_in extended permit udp host 10.2.55.131 host 192.168.0.65 eq snmp 
This policy is disabled as not allowed by NAT-Control."   
next
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for -z and using -E to enable EREs:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/(set comment)s? "[^"]*"/\1 " "/g' file
set action accept
set comment " "
next
```

The above will fail if your comments can include double quotes, escaped or not. If that can happen then you should include it in your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to use sed?

```
perl -0777pe 's/set comments "[^"]*"/set comments " "/gm' input.txt
```

produces

```
set action accept    
set comments " "   
next
```

from your sample input.

(If your comment string can include escaped quotes itself, it gets a lot harder.)

Comment: When I used the perl command, it removed anything inside of ""

edit 10000
  set srcintf " " 
  set dstintf " " 
  set srcaddr " " 
  set dstaddr " " 
  set service " " 
  set schedule " "
  set logtraffic disable
  set status enable
  set action deny
  set comments " "

Comment: You said you wanted to replace text in quotes and I assumed you meant all quoted strings. If you have some that you want to keep you'd have to adjust the regular expression, of course. I'll do so in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/set comments "/!b;:a;/"[^\\"]*\(\\.[^\\"]*\)*"/bb;N;ba;:b;s//" "/' file
```

This ignores lines other than those that contain the string  `set comments "`. It then checks to see if the line contains a closing unquoted double quote and if not accumulates lines until the condition is met. Finally it removes all characters between the starting/ending double quotes and replaces them with a single space.

P.S. I suspect that the OP did not mean to replace `comments` with `comment` however it a trivial change to the second regexp and the RHS of the substitution command if it is intended.